# METEOR - create template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, dynamic, meteor

Do meteor has a function of creating template dynamically ?

like template.create ?

example:

```
   <input class="button" value="create" class="create">
```

js:

```
    'click input.create' : function(){
          //do creating templates
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: creating a subtemplate dynamically .. after i clicked create button , it will create a template with the name given by the user and then load it inside a window plugin

Comment: Why not just have the template already available and just display it when the user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. Use the web inspector to look at the JavaScript code generated from a .html file and use that as your starting point.